# Outgoing data Service Bus for Windows Server

Tags: servicebus, azureservicebus

For the Service Bus for Windows Server performance counters are available for the number of incoming and outgoing messages per second. But a performance counter for the ***average*** incoming or outgoing messages in bytes is also available. But is there also a performance counter (or another solution) for the incoming (and/or) outgoing bytes for the service bus? (not network because it is for a development machine)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the counters seem to be documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj192996(v=azure.10).aspx

This is no specific counter for total bytes in/out.  If you can't do that with a network performance counter, it seems the only workaround is to multiply the number of messages in or out by the average message size.